# Получить random из Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица транспорта. Есть 30 записей которые я должен получать случайным образом. Каждый раз когда я открываю страницу, должен идти запрос к БД где я получаю 10 записей из 30 случайным образом. Как это сделать на MySQL?

Comment: Неужели `ORDER BY RAND()` больше не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Почему минусуют? актуально же ORDER BY rand() если нет пишите свой ответ.

Comment: Согласен, спасибо